# too high Code Coverage in KarmaJS with karma-coverage & Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, code-coverage, karma-coverage

I'm using Jasmine as the testing framework for my AngularJS application. I run the tests with the help of Grunt & KarmaJS. KarmaJS also generates the code coverage with the help of [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage).

Now I've created a model for configuaration data, which I also have to instantiate for other tests. Because of this instantiation I get a code coverage for this file although I haven't done any tests for it. Only because while the test run all of the lines were used, the coverage is 100%.

Now the question: Is there a way to specify in my tests which files they cover?

In PHP Unit there is an [@covers annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html) which specifies what code is covered with the test.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Since karma-coverage uses [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) under the hood, all configuration for Istanbul should work for karma-coverage.

In Istanbul, you can specify that [a block of code be ignored for coverage purposes](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md). You can try placing something like this at the top of your file:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
```

I haven't tried this myself, but I'd bet that this or something similar would do what you want it to do.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reponse and the link. But that is not what I want to do. This excludes code from being included in the coverage report. But I need to anotate my tests which code they cover.

With the ignore comment I annotate inside of the source lines of code which should not be considered in the coverage report.

But maybe someone found a nice workaround with the help of ignore but I can't see the solution here.